# Django: reverse_lazy() with a generic view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have two generic views (**CreateView** and **DetailView**).

In my CreateView after saving my form I want redirect to the DetailView to display my newly created object.

But an error occured : `Reverse for 'questions.views.DisplayQuestions' not found. 'questions.views.DisplayQuestions' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

**How can I call my DetailView with `reverse_lazy` ?**

.views:

```
class DisplayQuestions(ListView):
    model = Question
    context_object_name = "all_questions"
    template_name = "questions/home.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.order_by(self.kwargs['display_type'])


@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CreateQuestion(CreateView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'questions/nouveau.html'
    form_class = QuestionForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy(DisplayQuestion) # <-- This doesn't work !!!

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.profil = self.request.user.profil
        self.object = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^nouveau$', views.CreateQuestion.as_view()),
    url(r'(?P<display_type>\w+)', views.DisplayQuestions.as_view()),]
```

.forms:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question','categorie',)
```

Comment: Exactly what should be the `display_type`?

Comment: `display_type` should be the word `date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name each urls in your config as,

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^nouveau$', views.CreateQuestion.as_view(), name='create-question'),
    url(r'(?P<display_type>\w+)', views.DisplayQuestions.as_view(), name='display-question'),
]
```

and then access it as,

```
return reverse_lazy('display-question', kwargs={'display_type': 'your-display-type-value'})
```

**Reference:** [Reversing namespaced URLs --(doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls)

Comment: Thanks! But now I have this error `Reverse for 'display-questions' with no arguments not found` because I don't pass an argument. I would like to pass the word "date" as an argument. Could you help me ?